# Applying a function on every member of an Array in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've a column in a dataframe that's an array of string datatypes. I need to extract a portion the string thus I need to applying a regex of every element of the array.
So I want to apply this using the scala Dataframe API.

```
regexp_extract($"myString","(\\d+)-(\\d+)",1).cast(LongType)
```

on every member of the array.

It's simple to do on one string, but how do I do it on each item of the array?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform` to apply a function to every array element:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "myString", 
    expr("transform(myString, x -> cast(regexp_extract(x, '(\\\\d+)-(\\\\d+)',1) as bigint))")
)
```

Comment: Could you explain how the `transform` function works and where it is defined in Spark?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#transform

Comment: Thank you for the link. I just though that it might be a way to avoid using string expressions. But it looks like the `transform` function was only introduced in Spark 3.0. So with Spark 3.0 one can write the same in Scala: `df.withColumn("myString", transform(col("myString"), (x: Column) => regexp_extract(x,"(\\d+)-(\\d+)",1).cast(LongType)))`